# Command Error: python.exe can't open file

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, backend

I am trying the Google App Engine tutorial to make mobile assistant app using Eclipse. I am at the part where I have to try upload data to my local server. I am currently using Cygwin. However I am getting this error:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/appcfg.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory upload_data.sh: line 3: --config_file: command not found upload_data.sh: line 4: nobody@nowhere.com: command not found
```

I have no idea why this error is happening.

Thanks.

Comment: have you added the Google App Engine python packages to the PYTHONPATH?

Comment: How do you add GAE python packages to PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 1):

Since the explanation is a bit large to put it into a comment I will post it as answer.

First of all:

**Try run your program using the python interpreter of your Cygwin distro**. it seems GAE it's installed there.

if not the case, well ...

**Try to add GAE to the python path.**

Your code is trying to reach `/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/appcfg.py` this is surely due to an

```
import appcfg
```

that's why you need `/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/` to be added to the **PYTHONPATH**.

For accomplish that you can:

Add GAE to **PYTHONPATH** adding to your code:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/")
```

at some point before all GAE stuff began to be imported.

or you can use your python `site.py` file. This file must be located at: `C:\Python27\Lib\site.py`.

Open this file and read its content, there are a huge comment there which explain what and how you must proceed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am very new to Python I only installed it for doing this tutorial. I do not really understand what you mean by adding GAE to Pythonpath from code. Would it be possible that you expand on it a little more.

Comment: I edited that part, if my answer is usefull to you, don't forget give it a vote.

Comment: Do I add that piece of code to "appcfg.py"? So far following tutorial it's all been using Java.